# Why can't I use SwiftPM as a dependency using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, package-managers

I have the following Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "my-vapor-project",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-mysql-driver.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager", .branch("master")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: [
            .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
            .product(name: "FluentMySQLDriver", package: "fluent-mysql-driver"),
            .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
            .product(name: "SwiftPM", package: "swift-package-manager")
        ]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

When I save the file, Xcode attempts to resolve the dependencies automatically, and I get the following error and warning:

> Showing All Messages
>   /Users/sluther/Projects/my-vapor-project/Package.swift:
>   product dependency 'SwiftPM' in package 'swift-package-manager' not
>   found
>
> : dependency 'SwiftPM' is not used by any target

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that at the time of writing, Swift Package Manager could not be included as a dependency when using Swift Tools Version 5.2 which removed the old syntax for defining Product dependencies. Switching the Swift Tools Version to 5.1 resolved the issue.

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "my-vapor-project",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-mysql-driver.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager", .branch("master")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: [
            .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
            .product(name: "FluentMySQLDriver", package: "fluent-mysql-driver"),
            .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
            "SwiftPM"
        ]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

Comment: This is still happening for me when using swift tools 5.3. Downgrading to 5.1 throws different errors. I've seen projects using 5.2 that don't have this issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not dedicate more time to this and never got it figured out.